# How to get list of items by common code in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class in C#:

```
class AnalyteUnits {
  public string Analyte;
  public string Units;
}
```

So the data comes back looking like:

```
Analyte = "Ce", Units ="kg"
Analyte = "Fe", Units ="%"
Analyte = "Fe", Units = "g" etc etc
```

What I need is to shuffle this to look like:

```
analyte = "Fe", units = {"%", "g"}
```

How can I achieve this with LINQ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want as a result. `analyte = "Fe", units = {"%", "g"}` is not compatible with your `class AnalyteUnits`. `string` and `string[]` are two different things. So what type is `analyte = "Fe", units = {"%", "g"}` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) `Analyte`, e.g. given

```
AnalyteUnits[] data = new AnalyteUnits[] {
  new AnalyteUnits() { Analyte = "Ce", Units = "kg" },
  new AnalyteUnits() { Analyte = "Fe", Units = "%" },
  new AnalyteUnits() { Analyte = "Fe", Units = "g" },
};
```

You can put

```
var result = data
  .GroupBy(item => item.Analyte, item => item.Units)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToArray());

// Let's have a look:
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : {string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Another possibility is `Lookup` instead of dictionary:

```
var lookup = data
  .GroupBy(item => item.Analyte, item => item.Units)
  .ToLookup(group => group.Key, group => group); 

// Let's have a look:
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lookup
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : {string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RlJnAI)

Answer (score 1):

try use group by statement

```
           var result = from unit in units
            group unit by unit.Analyte
            into g
            select new { analyte = g.Key, units = g.Select(x=>x.Units).ToList() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a straight forward approach with a Dictionary<string, HashSet> to store and track the unique units for each analyte.

```
    Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> unitsByAnalyte = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (!unitsByAnalyte.ContainsKey(item.Analyte))
            unitsByAnalyte[item.Analyte] = new HashSet<string>();

        unitsByAnalyte[item.Analyte].Add(item.Units);
    }

    // Print the result
    foreach (var item in unitsByAnalyte)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Analyte: {item.Key}, Units:{{{string.Join(", ", item.Value.Select(value => $"\"{value}\""))}}}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SJtl0C)